# How to access mongodb data from Oracle server?

Tags: mongodb, oracle

We are using Oracle server and we need to fetch data from MongoDB. As RHEL 7 is supported for installing MongoDB drivers, and the one we use is RHEL 6.9. So drivers are not installed and dblink was not created. We are looking for other options to access this MongoDB server from Oracle server.

Please need help here.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a challenge because Oracle is a relational database whereas MongoDB is "NoSQL". A native connection is not possible.

Look for a MongoDB ODBC Driver, e.g.

- [MongoDB ODBC Driver](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/odbc-driver-for-the-mongodb-connector-for-business-intelligence)
- [Progress DataDirect ODBC Driver for MongoDB](https://www.progress.com/odbc/mongodb)
- [devart ODBC Driver for MongoDB](https://www.devart.com/odbc/mongodb/)
- [CData MongoDB ODBC Driver](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/mongodb/odbc/)
- [easysoft MongoDB ODBC Driver](https://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-mongodb-driver/index.html#section=tab-1)

Once you installed one of them, use the [Oracle Database Gateway for ODBC](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/odbcu/database-gateway-for-odbc-introduction.html) to access the MongoDB via the ODBC driver.

The configuration of this can be tricky, but it should be possible.

Almost any popular programming language is able to connect to an Oracle database as well to connect to MongoDB. So, you can write a program/script which copies data from one database to the other. However, if you like to use direct connection (i.e. database link in Oracle) the you have to use one of these ODBC driver.

Comment: The Oracle DB people would probably point out all the non-relational features it supports such as its document access [SODA](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/simple-oracle-document-access/adsdi/overview-soda.html#GUID-BE42F8D3-B86B-43B4-B2A3-5760A4DF79FB) and also its [JSON datatype support](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/index.html) both of which are great for JSON storage.

Comment: @ChristopherJones, `JSON` is not `BSON` and I thing the [Aggregation Framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) is much more powerful than what you can get in Oracle (in terms of JSON/BSON operation). Neither Oracle nor MongoDB is the "better" one, they just have different approach and I think both have their rights to exist.

Answer (score 0):

In combination with the Oracle Gateway for ODBC, you solve this problem via any of the following solutions:

1. ODBC or JDBC (via ODBC-to-JDBC Bridge) Drivers and Oracle's Database Integrator for ODBC
2. ODBC- and/or JDBC-compliant Data Virtualization Platform

### ODBC Driver and Oracle Data Integration (ODI) Gateway

1. Attach Oracle to MongoDB Driver. You can use a native JDBC driver, or a JDBC-to-ODBC Bridge Driver plus a native ODBC driver
2. Perform your Data Manipulation operations via ODI

OpenLink JDBC-to-ODBC Bridge Drivers provide enhanced DBMS virtualization that increases compatibility between JDBC client apps and 3rd party ODBC Drivers.

### Data Virtualization Platform Solution

Here's how it works, given that you have ODBC access to each of Oracle and MySQL Database Management Systems (DBMS), using either a native ODBC Driver or a native JDBC Driver with an OBDC-to-JDBC Bridge:

1. Attach the Data Virtualization Platform to the MongoDB instance
2. Attach the Data Virtualization Platform to the Oracle instance
3. Perform your Data Manipulation (DML) operations on Data managed by either DBMS, as though they were in local tables in the Data Virtualization Layer

Our Virtuoso Multi-Model Database Management and Virtualization Platform is an example of a Data Virtualization solution that operates in the manner described above.

### Related

- [Data Virtualization for Beginners](https://community.openlinksw.com/t/virtuoso-data-virtualization-for-beginners-sql-data-sources/1573)
- [OpenLink ODBC-to-ODBC Bridge Drivers](https://uda.openlinksw.com/db-ODBC/) — increase compatibility of third party ODBC Drivers with Oracle's ODBC Gateway
- [OpenLink JDBC-to-ODBC Bridge Drivers](https://uda.openlinksw.com/db-ODBC/) — enable use of third party ODBC Drivers with Oracle's ODI middleware
- [OpenLink JDBC-to-JDBC Bridge Drivers](https://uda.openlinksw.com/db-JDBC/) — increase compatibility of third party JDBC Drivers with Oracle's ODI middleware
- [OpenLink ODBC-to-JDBC Bridge Drivers](https://uda.openlinksw.com/db-JDBC/) — enable use of third party JDBC Drivers with Oracle's ODBC Gateway
- [Using Oracle's ODI and the OpenLink JDBC-to-ODBC Bridge to connect to Microsoft Excel data sources](https://community.openlinksw.com/t/using-the-oracle-data-integrator-odi-12-2-1-with-microsoft-excel-data-via-the-openlink-jdbc-to-odbc-bridge-drivers/1041)
- [Virtuoso Data Virtualization Platform](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com)